# Show half of image with hover and CSS

Tags: html, css, image

How could to show left side of image at begin, and show right side on mouse hover.

```css
body{
  background:gray;
}

img{
    width: 100px;
}

img:hover {

}
```

```html
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdqr.png" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you yourself can remake this code for your task.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0;
}

img:hover {
  object-position: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdqr.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

I will sugest to add a container with two elements inside : your image and a div that will hide half of your image, and on hover we will remove div to show your img

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:2px solid black;
}

.container:hover .bg{
  width:0%;
}

.bg{
  transition:all .2s;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background:white;
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdqr.png"/>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre not clear what you want. I think you want different color while hovering on the picture.

For this crop this picture to a single object. Then you can use css grayscale filter on hover.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}

img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQdqr.png">
```